# Flex/AS3: Is there a way to make Flash Player autorun with the "100%" option instead of "show all"

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash

I mean from AS3. My application is just a swf and is run by a simple Flash Player (Proyector). It isn't neither AIR nor web-embeded.

I need to access to some Flash Player's options to create a default state. For example: every time my application is run I need to activate "100%" view and centre the Flash Player on the screen (desktop).

Regards.

Comment: If you want to have control over your application, why not just make it an Air app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not.  You can however set an explicit `minHeight`, `height`, and `maxHeight` of your flex application.  Then regardless of how they resize it, it will always be in the bounds of the sizes you have specified.

```
    ... height="600" maxHeight="600" minHeight="600" framerate="15" ...
```